# How to load IconCompat with AdaptiveBitmap using Glide

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-glide, android-bubbles

How to leverage Glide cache for loading notification icons? Those are [IconCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/IconCompat) used in the [Person](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/Person.Builder?hl=en) object in the [MessagingStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle) notifications and [Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts). Also, [Bubbles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles) require using both of those.

I used Glid as fallowing:

```
private IconCompat loadIcon(String url) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().override(ADAPTIVE_BITMAP_SIZE);
    Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(G.app).asBitmap().apply(requestOptions).load(url).submit().get();
    return IconCompat.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I got several questions about this solution

- What should be the size of `ADAPTIVE_BITMAP_SIZE`?
- When will the bitmap get recycled?
- How to handle errors in loading the bitmap?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom `TargetWrapper` for the async loading icon.
The config your Glide using your TargetWrapper instance.

```
asyncLoadIcon("http://YOUR_URL.com"){
    val person = Person.Builder()
        .setName("John Doe")
        .setIcon(it)

    notificationManagerHelper.notify(
        person.build()
    )
}
```

Helper function for async loading bitmap then wrap into Icon

```
 private fun asyncLoadIcon(avatar: String?, block: (IconCompat?) -> Unit) {
        if (avatar.isNullOrEmpty())
            block(null)
        else {
            GlideHelper.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(requireContext(), avatar) { result ->
                if (result?.isSuccess() == true)
                    block(IconCompat.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(result.toData()))
                else block(null)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the Glide image request function with retrieving bitmap with a callback.

```
fun createWithAdaptiveBitmap(
    context: Context,
    url: String,
    listener: ((Result<Bitmap>?) -> Unit)
) {
    val options = RequestOptions()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
        .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
        .dontTransform()

    Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .apply(options)
        .load(url)
        .into(CustomTargetWrapper(listener))
}
```

CustomTargetWrapper class for async loading bitmap.

```
class CustomTargetWrapper(
    private val listener: ((Result<Bitmap>?) -> Unit)
) : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {

    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
        listener.invoke(Result.Success(resource))
    }

    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
        listener.invoke(null)
    }

    override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
        super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable)
        listener.invoke(Result.Error(IOException("Glide load failed")))
    }
}
```